# Symfony 2 form change fields name

Tags: php, forms, symfony

Hello is it possible to map fields inside Symfony2 form object, for example my template has field named: "title", but symfony form type want this field as "progress[title]" is it possible to map "title" as "progress[title]" inside form builder?

example:

```
$builder->add('title')
```

name:

```
public function getName()
{
    return 'progress';
}
```

controller handle request needs now "progress[title]", i want send just "title"

```
    $progress = new Progress();
    $form = $this->createForm(new ProgressType(), $progress);

    $form->handleRequest($request);//here comes "title"
```

Comment: it does this stuff automatically when you use $form->createView() / pass to view & display your form in view as expected per documentation

Comment: but i handle ajax request, not generated via symfony

Comment: I suggest to use the symfony2 way of generating forms and then adapt your javascript to it. That's way more stable and less prone to changes.

Answer (score 1):

**This does not work:**
Maybe you can just remove the name?

```
public function getName()
{
    return 'progress';
}
```

**This does:**
Else if you want to keep your name and can register the type as service, you can maybe do it like this: Use createNamed with "null" as first parameter.

```
$form = $formFactory->createNamed(null, 'progress', $progress);
```

**Edit:**
For PUT try this:

```
$form = $formFactory->createNamed(null, 'progress', $progress, array('method'=>'PUT'));
```

Comment: when i remove the name i still got table like [title].

Comment: when i add method=>'PUT' values is not bined         $factory = Forms::createFormFactory();
        $form = $factory->createNamed(null, new ProgressType())->add('submit', 'submit');
        $form->handleRequest(null, $request); //without PUT values are binded

Comment: $form->handleRequest($request) should work. I think there is no method handleRequest($something, $request), so just leave out the first paramter

Comment: but $form->handleRequest($request) throws exception that 1st except parameter should be type "null"